# Using stringsdict with interpolation

Tags: swift, swiftui, string-interpolation, localizable.strings, swift5

I am attempting to use the `stringsdict` file with new Swift 5.1 advanced interpolation. After much jumping through hoops, I was actually able to get a *very* simple example to work:

```
    <key>format.%lld</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@num_formats@</string>
        <key>num_formats</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>lld</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>Format</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>Formats</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Now I can reference it in `Text` for example like so:

```swift
Text("format.\(count)", comment: "formats string")
```

and I'll properly get "Format" for 1 and "Formats" for everything else. But now I have a more advanced use case. I want a `num_formats` variable and then a `format` variable. For `1`, it should just print `format` (no `num_formats` interpolation). For many, I want `"\(numFormats) x \(format)"`

I tried setting up these 2 variables in the `stringsdict` like so:

```
    <key>quantity.%lld x %@</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@num_quantity@ %#@format@</string>
        <key>format</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>@</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%@</string>
        </dict>
        <key>num_quantity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>lld</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%lld x</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

I expected to be able to use this by calling:

```swift
Text("quantity.\(formats.count) x \("Vinyl")", comment: "format quantity string")
```

Instead, I get `(null)` when `formats.count` is `1`, and `2 x (null)` when it's not `1`. What's the proper way to do this?

EDIT: I was able to get some of it fixed by removing `x` from the `NSStringLocalizedFormatKey` value. It was `<string>%#@num_quantity@ x %#@format@</string>` previously, and I changed it to `<string>%#@num_quantity@ %#@format@</string>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I can just use normal format specifiers in the key itself and not run them through the pluralization portion:

```
    <key>quantity.%lld x %@</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@num_quantity@ %@</string>
        <key>num_quantity</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>lld</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>%lld x</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Leaving this up in case anyone else wants to struggle with SwiftUI + string interpolation.